# Zend_Pdf stream in Internet Explorer 8 via HTTPS

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf, https, download

i use Zend_Pdf to create a new pdf and then force the browser to download the file. The site is only accessible via https. This is my output for the file:

```
$output = $pdf->render();
$response = new Zend_Controller_Response_Http();
$response->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="xyz.pdf"');
$response->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
$response->setHeader('Content-length', strlen($output));
$response->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'private');
$response->setHeader('Expires', '0');
$response->setHeader('Pragma', 'private');
$response->setBody($output);
$response->sendResponse();
```

I've read many articles regarding the right headers for this purpose, but something is not working in Internet Exporer 8. Everytime you try to generate and download the pdf the download dialog shows up but it says that theres nothing to download. The filename is wrong (instead of xyz.pdf it shows the name of the site the generating form is on)

Tested and working in: Firefox, Chrome, IE9, Opera, Safari

I also tried the different possibilities for the Cache-Controle header or Pragma Header, like so many articles talk about.

Comment: You might want to answer your own question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, third parameter is the overwrite option.

```
$response->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'private', true);
$response->setHeader('Expires', '0', true);
$response->setHeader('Pragma', 'private', true);
```